# How to typeset the limit of a sequence like so?

Tags: math-mode

I want to write this:

[image]

I tried with `$x_n \to_{n \to 0} 0$` but the `$n \to 0$` doesn't go under the right arrow, it goes under but on the right, and I want it under but in the center, as in the picture above.

Comment: You should check out [Custom-length arrows, text over and under](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27545/5764) (possible duplicate).

Comment: Ingo suggested as a comment to my answer that you should change the title of your question, to make it clearer for the search engines, since it seems the content of the answers is focused on extensible subscripted arrows, rather than sequences.  I'll leave that for you to decide.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can also use the function `\xrightarrow`:

```
$ x_n \xrightarrow[n \to 0]{} 0$
```

[image: Result]

The user's guide of the **amsmath** package says :

> `\xleftarrow` and `\xrightarrow` produce arrows that extend
>   automatically to accommodate unusually wide subscripts or
>   superscripts. These commands take one optional argument (the
>   subscript) and one mandatory argument (the superscript, possibly
>   empty)"

Comment: Is there a way to obtain a shorter arrow? I think that one is too long

Comment: @SuperTroll I know it has to be written but, "in my code my arrow is shorter"...

Comment: @AndreaL. I know, I'm just trying to find out if there's a way to make the arrow shorter with this shorter code.

Comment: @SuperTroll If I remember correctly, to modify the length of the arrow inside the macro `\n<>arrow` you have to add a complex re-definition because the final lenght is fixed.

Comment: @SuperTroll IMHO, this is the right length

Comment: @SuperTroll I agree with karlkoeller's opinion about the length of the arrow, but of you want to reduce it a bit, you could say something like `$x_n \xrightarrow[{\makebox[12pt][c]{$\scriptstyle n \to 0$}}]{} 0$`.

Comment: What's with the bizarre changes in thickness along the arrow? Is it due to compression or something?

Comment: @Thomas it looks like compression to me, rather than an artefact of the antialiasing, because it's only on the long arrow.  Odd in a .png -- although they can be lossily compressed it's not usual.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the function of `\underset` and `\overset`, in this case an arrow is simply defined with:

```
\underset{n\to 0}{\longrightarrow}
```

Which points the expression related to "n" under the second argument, here there are two versions depending on the size of the underset (using `\scriptscriptstyle`):

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
\begin{document}
%
\[
X_n\underset{n\to 0}{\longrightarrow}0 \qquad%
X_n\underset{\scriptscriptstyle{n\to 0}}{\longrightarrow}0
\]
%
\end{document}
```

Which yields:

> [image]

Answer (score 7):

If you wanted to change the depth of the underset below the arrow (for example, to 1 pt), then this could be done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\( X_n  \mathrel{\stackunder[1pt]{\longrightarrow}{\scriptscriptstyle n \rightarrow 0}} 0 \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, one could use something of Heiko's approach using `\xrightarrow`, but achieving a more snug fit like Fran's result, with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
$ x_n \mathrel{\stackunder[-7.5pt]{\xrightarrow[%
  \scriptscriptstyle\phantom{n \to 0}]{}}{\scriptscriptstyle n \to 0\,}} 0$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, one could create the long arrow manually, and stack the underset below it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\( X_n  \mathrel{\stackunder[-1pt]{-\mkern-5mu-\mkern-10mu\longrightarrow}{%
  \scriptscriptstyle n \rightarrow 0}} 0 \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

The one thing all three solutions have in common is they use `stackengine` to underset the subscript, which gives flexibility on the vertical location of the underset.

[Thanks to Qrrbrbirlbel for reminding me I forgot the `\mathrel`]

Comment: The spacing around the `\longrightarrow` is wrong, see the `amsmath` solutions.

Comment: Or also `$X_{n}\;_{\mathrel{\stackunder[-5.5pt]{\overrightarrow{\phantom{HHs}}}{_{n\to0}}}}\;0$` that is almost identical to `$ x_n \xrightarrow[n \to 0]{} 0$`

Comment: @Fran, yes, but the whole reason I stuck to the stack approach is to show how it can be made slightly different in appearance, *if* the nominal vertical spacing is found undesirable.  To make it mimic the `\xrightarrow` formulation is just wasting extra keystrokes.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, I  understood perfectly that the advantage of your method is the flexibility of adjusting vertical space. Just wanted to apply to my example, but I did not seem right include this as part of my answer. Setting `\stackunder` to mimic `\xrightarrow` spacing (too much for my taste) was just to obtain the reference of -5.5pt, so anyone can imagine how close/far must be the setting of this value to fit  their preferences.

Comment: @Fran I see.  I'm sorry for not having understood.   I see your point now.  But by all means, feel free to demonstrate the package in your answers, so that I'm not the only one touting it               8~(  ..

Comment: We should make the title of this question clearer. No search engine will index this properly, while many people will be looking for this.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a plain version:

```
$$ X_n \mathrel{\mathop{\kern0pt\longrightarrow}\limits_{n\to0}} 0 $$ \bye
```

which could be shortened like `\buildrel` with `\def\relop#1#2{\mathrel{\mathop{\kern0pt #1}\limits_{#2}}}` to be `X_n \relop\longrightarrow{n\to0} 0`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: MWE]

```
$X_{n\overrightarrow{_{\;\;n\to0\;\;\;}}}0$
```

This is not as elegant  as `\xrightarrow`, but like this command (and unlike `\underset`method) the long arrow could longer (required for some wider  than `n \to 0`).  The difference with `\xrightarrow` is that (a) do not need the `amsmath` package, (b) long arrow could be also as shorter as the text under it, (c) a smaller arrowhead (d) produce a more compact formula. Bug or feature, depending of what you want. But in case of be regarded as a bug, the horizontal spacing can be solved adding some more spaces. The vertical spacing cab be solved following the Steven's answer. In this MWE the second formula have exactly the same horizontal spacing that using `\xarrow`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$X_{n\overrightarrow{_{\;\;n\to0\;\;\;}}}0$

$X_{n\;\,\overrightarrow{_{\;n\to0\;\;\,}}}\;0$
\end{document}
```