# Can I make an arrow of length x in latex?

Tags: arrows

I was making a quick graph in TexStudio, but I founnd I can not make an arrow of a  length X. The only way I found to do what I want is this: [Minimum length for \xrightarrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6835/minimum-length-for-xrightarrow)

In my opinion this is a workaround and it probably can be done neater/faster with a package of sort.

EDIT: The reason the quoted answer does not work for me is because I also need a diagonal arrow with length x.

Comment: You can use `\rotatebox` from `graphicx` or a drawing package such as `tikz`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx Reinder! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of theis site.

Comment: In conclusion: Can you make an arrow of length x in latex?
Yes but it is not without restrictions and there is no special package or option to make it possible.
For some things it is better to switch to a drawing program and use a picture. Thanks for the usefull help and comments!

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

$\xrightarrow{\makebox[2cm]{1}}$

\end{document}
```

change the fonts style for the 1 if you need it smaller.

[image]

Comment: Your awnser does produce what I asked for, but in the same way as the answer I linked to. One of the problems is that it only works with the horizontal arrow and not a diagonal one.

Comment: `\rotatebox{45}{$\xrightarrow{\makebox[2cm]{}}$}`

Answer (score 6):

Something that someone regards as overkill may be regarded by other people as useful.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}

\def\arrow#1{\pspicture[shift=2pt](#1,0)\psline{->}(#1,0)\endpspicture}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
$f:x \arrow{2} x^2$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice, this more or less what I meant. What about diagonal lines?

Comment: Unfortunatly I get: Undefined control sequence $f:x \arrow{2}