# Table: make one row and one column in bold and add a axis name as shown in the picture

Tags: tables

I would like to create my table as shown in the picture.

I have attached the LaTeX code I have written. How to modify it, to get the same as that in the picture?

[image]

```
\begin{table}[h]
     \begin{center}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.4cm}
       \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
       \begin{tabular}{|c|ccccccccccc|}\hline
        &-50& -40 &-30&-20&-10&0&10&20&30&40&50 \\ \hline
        50 &0& 0 &0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 
        40 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0&0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &0 \\ 
        30 & 0 & 0 & 0& 10 & 13 & 18 & 14 & 7 & 0 &0 &0\\ 
        20 &    0&  0&  14& 19 & 22 &   24  &22&    18& 12& 0  &0\\ 
        10& 0&  8&  20& 24& 27& 27& 24& 21& 12&0&0\\ 
        0&  3 & 12& 22  &25&    27& 30& 27& 24& 18 &4&0\\ 
        -10&    6&  16  &24&    27  &27&    30& 27& 24& 17& 8 &0\\ 
        -20 &0& 10& 18& 22& 27& 27& 23& 21& 12&0 &0\\ 
        -30&    0&  4&  14& 18& 22& 24& 18& 15& 13&0&0\\ 
        -40 &0& 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0 &0&0\\ 
         -50 &0& 0 &0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some `\multicolumn` and `\multirow` commands as well as using arrows of specific size [from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114198/134144), you can achieve the desired result. For the bold column, I hvave used `>{\bfseries}c` instead of `c` and for the bold row, I have repeatedly sed `\textbf{}`. For a more automated version of bold rows in tables, [see for example here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309837/134144) . Lastly, please note that I have also replaced the `center` environment by the `\centering` command as the former adds unwanted vertical white space arount the tabular.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.4cm}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
    \begin{tabular}{c|>{\bfseries}c|ccccccccccc|}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{$\xleftarrow{\makebox[5.25cm]{}}$} & x & \multicolumn{5}{c}{$\xrightarrow{\makebox[4.75cm]{}}$}\\ \cline{2-13}
        & & \textbf{-50} &  \textbf{-40} &  \textbf{-30} & \textbf{-20} & \textbf{-10} &  \textbf{0} &  \textbf{10} &  \textbf{20} &  \textbf{30} &  \textbf{40} &  \textbf{50} \\ \cline{2-13}
        \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{$\xrightarrow{\makebox[1.25cm]{}}$}} & 50 &0& 0 &0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 
       & 40 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0&0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &0 \\ 
       & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0& 10 & 13 & 18 & 14 & 7 & 0 &0 &0\\ 
       & 20 &    0&  0&  14& 19 & 22 &   24  &22&    18& 12& 0  &0\\ 
       & 10& 0&  8&  20& 24& 27& 27& 24& 21& 12&0&0\\ 
      y & 0&  3 & 12& 22  &25&    27& 30& 27& 24& 18 &4&0\\ 
      \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{-90}{$\xrightarrow{\makebox[1.25cm]{}}$}}  & -10&    6&  16  &24&    27  &27&    30& 27& 24& 17& 8 &0\\ 
       & -20 &0& 10& 18& 22& 27& 27& 23& 21& 12&0 &0\\ 
       & -30&    0&  4&  14& 18& 22& 24& 18& 15& 13&0&0\\ 
       & -40 &0& 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0 &0&0\\ 
       & -50 &0& 0 &0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ \cline{2-13}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

Regarding the request in the comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.4cm}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
    \begin{tabular}{c|>{\bfseries}c|ccccccccccc|}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{5}{r}{\multirow{2}{*}{$\xleftarrow{\makebox[5.25cm]{}}$}} & x &  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\multirow{2}{*}{$\xrightarrow{\makebox[4.75cm]{}}$}}\\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & & & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{in mm}\\ \cline{2-13}
        & & \textbf{-50} &  \textbf{-40} &  \textbf{-30} & \textbf{-20} & \textbf{-10} &  \textbf{0} &  \textbf{10} &  \textbf{20} &  \textbf{30} &  \textbf{40} &  \textbf{50} \\ \cline{2-13}
        \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{$\xrightarrow{\makebox[1.25cm]{}}$}} & 50 &0& 0 &0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 
       & 40 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0&0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &0 \\ 
       & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0& 10 & 13 & 18 & 14 & 7 & 0 &0 &0\\ 
       & 20 &    0&  0&  14& 19 & 22 &   24  &22&    18& 12& 0  &0\\ 
      y & 10& 0&  8&  20& 24& 27& 27& 24& 21& 12&0&0\\ 
      in mm & 0&  3 & 12& 22  &25&    27& 30& 27& 24& 18 &4&0\\ 
      \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{-90}{$\xrightarrow{\makebox[1.5cm]{}}$}}  & -10&    6&  16  &24&    27  &27&    30& 27& 24& 17& 8 &0\\ 
       & -20 &0& 10& 18& 22& 27& 27& 23& 21& 12&0 &0\\ 
       & -30&    0&  4&  14& 18& 22& 24& 18& 15& 13&0&0\\ 
       & -40 &0& 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0 &0&0\\ 
       & -50 &0& 0 &0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ \cline{2-13}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello,
I try to write X in mm and the distance between the 0th column increases. If i had to write "in mm" i=on the next line. How to do it

Comment: Like one of these? https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJGbI.png

Comment: Yes for both, X and Y

Comment: Please see my updated answer for a suggestion on how to add `in mm` to both `x` and `y`.

Comment: \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & & & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{in mm}\\ \cline{2-13} 
I get an error for this line

Comment: It would be interesting to know which error message you recieve. Also do you get the error with the MWE from my answer or if you use the code in your actual document?

Comment: If I use the actual code in my answer, it shows an error at "\\" this symbol of the line, which I mentioned above.

Comment: \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & &&& \multicolumn{3}{c}{in mm}&&&&\\ \cline{2-13}
If i use this the error is gone but the in cm position is slightly changed.. I tried to adjust &&& to left and right side , but it doesnt line exactly next to X