# Horizontal and vertical arrow over table (tabularx) environment

Tags: tables, tabularx, arrows

I have a simple table, see attached pic, and I would like a horizontal arrow over the first row, from left to right. 
Another arrow next to the first column, vertical.

For both these arrow I would like text, on the arrow. 
The horizontal arrow should say, increasing complication. The vertical arrow should say increasing complexity.

Thanks all.

[image: my table]

Comment: Do these arrows have to go through the cells contents ?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! nice explained wish, however, what you try so far? this is not site "we-do-your-task-instead-of-you"

Comment: Here is an answer to a similar question using `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473049/134144

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tikzmark`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline
\tikzmark{a}aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb&ccccccccccccccccccc\tikzmark{c}\\\hline
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\\\hline
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\\\hline
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\\\hline
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\\\hline
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\\\hline
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\\\hline
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\\\hline
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\\\hline
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\\\hline
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\\\hline
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\\\hline
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\\\hline
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\\\hline
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\\\hline
\tikzmark{d}dddddddddddddddd&eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&fffffffffffffffff\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[-latex] ([ shift={(0,4ex)}]pic cs:a) -- node[above] {increasing complication} ([ shift={(0,4ex)}]pic cs:c);
\draw[-latex] ([ shift={(-3ex,0.7ex)}]pic cs:a) -- node[below,sloped] {increasing complexity} ([ shift={(-3ex,0)}]pic cs:d);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, it worked.