# Math.symbols in TeX

Tags: math-mode, symbols, arrows

1. How can I draw three dots on a letter (similar to \dot, \ddot)?
2. How can I draw {t\to\infty} over a {\longrightarrow}?
3. How can I modify the length of a horizontal {\arrow}?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you conferm you need this in plain TeX? If yes, then please add the specific tag.

Comment: Anticipating, that you actually are ok with using LaTeX, at least for your first two questions, please have a look at this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39230/97536
For the third, maybe look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6835/minimum-length-for-xrightarrow

Comment: @campa you might want to undelete your answer until the LaTeX or TeX question is answered.

Comment: @DG' Looking at the other questions from the OP I'm rather sure plain TeX is meant.

Comment: Still, your answer is good, and Matthias Arras just pointed out that the OP accepted LaTeX answers in the past.

Comment: I do not see the command !!!

Answer (score 5):

The extensible arrow can be coded in plain TeX. One could basically copy and adapt the code from `amsmath`, but I choose here a shorter way:

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\xrightarrow{\futurelet\let@token\@xrightarrow}
\def\@xrightarrow{%
   \ifx\let@token[%
      \def\next{\@@xrightarrow}%
   \else
      \def\next{\@@xrightarrow[]}%
   \fi
   \next}
\def\@@xrightarrow[#1]#2{%
   \mathrel{%
      \mathop{%
        \setbox0=\hbox{\rightarrowfill}%
        \setbox1=\vbox{\hbox{\m@th$\scriptstyle\mkern5mu{#2}\mkern9mu$}
                       \hbox{\m@th$\scriptstyle\mkern5mu{#1}\mkern9mu$}
                       \copy0}
        \hbox to \wd1{\unhbox0}%
        }\limits
        \ifx&#1&\else_{#1\mkern3mu}\fi
        \ifx&#2&\else^{#2\mkern3mu} \fi
    }
}
\catcode`@=12
```

Caveat: The test for emptyness `\ifx&#1&...` is not very safe.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER (LaTeX)**
The basic package `amsmath` provides tools to do all three things. The three dots can be obtained by `\dddot`, while `\xrightarrow` and `\xleftarrow` provide extensible arrows with possibly text above/below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\dddot{x} \\
a \xrightarrow{t\to\infty}b \\
a \to b \longrightarrow c \xrightarrow{\qquad} d
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. In Unicodeland with system fonts, `unicode-math` package defines a `\dddot` accent (as well as a `\ddddot` one), so not an answer if legacy font processing is required.

`\dddot` looks like this:

[image: dddot accent]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,varwidth,border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\usepackage{accents}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[Colour=blue]
\setmathfontface\masana{Asana Math}
\setmathfontface\mdejavu{DejaVu Math}
\setmathfontface\mtgdeja{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
\setmathfontface\mpagella{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfontface\mbonum{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
\setmathfontface\mschola{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\setmathfontface\mtermes{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfontface\mlatin{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfontface\mcambria{Cambria Math}
\setmathfontface\mfira{Fira Math}
\setmathfontface\mfreeserif{FreeSerif}
\setmathfontface\mlibert{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfontface\mnoto{Noto Sans Symbols}
\setmathfontface\mqui{Quivira}
\setmathfontface\mstixtwo{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfontface\mstixgen{STIXGeneral}
\setmathfontface\msymbola{Symbola}
\setmathfontface\mgaramond{\detokenize{Garamond-Math}}
\newcommand\mfsize{\Huge}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}


\newcommand\themassym{\dddot }
\begin{document}
\section*{Sampling {\mfsize $\themassym $}}

\vspace{24pt}

\begin{tabular}{rccl}
XITS Math & \mfsize $\themassym$ & \mfsize $\mcambria \themassym$ & Cambria Math \\ 
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Asana Math & \mfsize $\masana {\themassym}$ & \mfsize $\mfira \themassym$ & Fira Math \\ 
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
DejaVu Math & \mfsize $\mdejavu \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mfreeserif \themassym$ & FreeSerif \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Bonum Math & \mfsize $\mbonum \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mlibert \themassym$ & Libertinus Math \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre DejaVu Math & \mfsize $\mtgdeja \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mnoto \themassym$ & Noto Sans Symbols \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Pagella Math & \mfsize $\mpagella \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mqui \themassym$ & Quivira \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Schola Math & \mfsize $\mschola \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mstixtwo \themassym$ &STIX Two Math \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Termes Math & \mfsize $\mtermes \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mgaramond \themassym$ & Garamond-Math \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Latin Modern Math & \mfsize $\mlatin \themassym$ & \mfsize $\msymbola \themassym$ & Symbola \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: But the OP wants TeX if I am not mistaken...

Answer (score 2):

You could to use this code (MWE with the explanations in the comments `%%%%`) with a combination of `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}` and `tikz-cd` for example as into this screenshot:

[image]

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\dddotup{x},  
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2cm] %%%% to increase the lenght of the arrow
a \arrow[r, "t\to\infty"] & b
\end{tikzcd}\]
A chain of elements:
\begin{tikzcd}
    a \arrow[r] &[4em] b \arrow[r] &[7em]  c %%%% <---- to increase the lenght of the % arrow arbitrarily [4em] and [7em]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

At the least you can see that `\dddotup` with `mtpro2` also in lite version produces the dots on the character in an optimal way. See the guide at the page 15 (Using the MathTımeProfessional II fonts - 
with LATEX - 
Walter Schmidt
2008/1/23).

[image]